# Can you use "nor" if the sentence does not have a "neither" but instead some other negative word?

Tags: grammaticality, neither-nor

Would it be correct to say "you will not have statistical data nor anecdotal evidence to analyze"?

Should the "nor" be an "or"? Does the "not have" function somewhat like a "neither"?

Comment: I think there's an implied "either" in there. That is "you will not have *either* statistical data or anecdotal evidence." But I'm not altogether confident.

Comment: The use of *to analyze* at the end is unusual with *nor* in the context of the sentence. I would more commonly expect it to be one of the following instead: (1) *You will **not** have statistical data **nor** anecdotal evidence.* (2) *You will **have neither** statistical data **nor** anecdotal evidence **to analyze**.* The sentence exactly as written in the question is an unusual mix of the two.

Comment: It would be perfectly idiomatic to say "you will not have statistical data nor will you have anecdotal evidence to analyze".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* p1309,

> *Nor* appears as a coordinator paired correlatively with *neither*,
> or non-correlatively as a variant of *or* in negative contexts.

As this is clearly a negative context, the use of *nor* is prefectly acceptable.

Examples of this usage may be found in quality writing:

> Ultimately, I saw a system that often does **not have the time nor the
> inclination to care** about the kids inside it. (Teaching doesn't count;
> Sachar, E;Washington Monthly;1990 (Sep))
>
> The reason the CPA firm was willing to let the clients go was that the
> firm at the time did **not have the capability nor the desire** **to serve**
> small- to mid-sized clients that needed help in software selection,
> set up, maintenance, and training. (Growing a Nontraditional
> Accounting Firm: Warren and Associates; Bagranoff, Nancy; Turner,
> Leslie; Journal of Information Systems; 2004 (Fall))
>
> People who suffer from this kind of political and social upheaval do
> **not have the time nor the enthusiasm** **to admire** their artists. (   Mario
> Bencastro on the character of words; Mujica, B; Rascon, S.G.;Americas;
> Vol. 43 Issue 4, p24; 1991)